# Order of anchor directive's compilation

Tags: angularjs

ngClick and the anchor directive share the same priority ( 0 ). Note that ngHrefs priority is 99.

```
<a ng-href="" ng-click="performAction()">Perform Action</a>
```

ngHref will compile 1st based on its priority.

Will ngClick or the anchor directive compile next, or is it undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)**:

*"The order of directives with the same priority is undefined."*

Comment: I guess what I'm hung up on is in this response. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/3HsNz4ncnYA/I5itlZQgoq0J  It is suggested that directives are compiled depth first down. The case of <a><b></b></a> is clear to me but not <a c></a>. Is c considered to be deeper or equal height?

Comment: Even in this response it mentions it: _"Moreover if you have multiple directives on an element, they are compiled in order of their priority value, highest first, with directives of the same priority having undetermined order."_ `<a c></a>` features 2 directives on the same element. The order of compilation is determined by their priorities (and is undefined in case of equal priorities).